# Problems with accessing job PID in LINUX shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell

if I run the expression

```
ps -fu $USER| grep 'mount' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'
```

in the command line, I get - as expected - the PID of the processes containing "mount" in their description.

I want to achieve the following to kill certain background processes programmatically. The following code in the shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mountcmd="ps -fu $USER| grep 'mount' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}' "
mountpid=$(eval "$mountcmd")
echo "Found existing background job PID: " "$mountpid"
```

does not provide the PID, but the output of echo is:

```
Found existing background job PID:  wgeithne  6284     1  0 17:09 pts/3    00:00:00 minikube mount /u/wgeithne/bin/grafana/config:/grafana
```

How do I get the only the PID as output of my script?

Comment: What is `$2` in the script?  Very likely, it is not the string that you want to pass as the argument to `print` in `awk`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Surely the intent is simply to pull out the second field?

Comment: Perhaps my comment was unclear.  In the definition of `mountcmd`, the `$2` is being interpolated (very likely as the empty string), so the command being executed is `awk '{print }'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stupid `eval` trick requires additional escaping of the dollar sign in the Awk script. But really, a massively superior solution is to avoid stupid `eval` tricks.

Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

If you really need to reinvent `pidof`, probably get rid of the antipatterns.

```
mountpids=$(ps -fu "$USER" | awk '/[m]ount/ { print $2 }')
```